# Can I start an inversion structure with something other than the specific negative or limiting adverbs or use them as dependent clauses?

Tags: inversion

I have recently learned about inversion. In all examples I have seen, a negative or limiting adverb takes place at the beginning of the sentence like this:

> Seldom do I sleep early these days.

But can I also move the "seldom" to the middle of the sentence and say:

> 1 These days, seldom do I sleep early.

> 2 I used to sleep early, but seldom do I sleep early nowadays.

Or can we use them as dependent clauses:

> 3 This is a very rare creature that barely can you find.

Comment: Yes: you can. In all your examples, the negative word "seldom" triggers subject-auxiliary inversion. Note that in 1. we might more naturally say "I seldom sleep early these days"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use of a negative or limiting adverb triggers [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](https://www.thoughtco.com/subject-auxiliary-inversion-1692003) (SAI). Such inversions can also follow other adverbs, particularly adverbs of frequency, degree, or method, even when used in a positive sense. Such inverted structures are often at the start of a sentence, particularity when forming questions, but can also be found in a later clause or otherwise not at the start of a sentence.

There are other forms of inversion as well, particularly ***Subject-Verb Inversion***. See [this ThoughtCo article](https://www.thoughtco.com/inversion-grammar-term-1691193) for a discussion with a number of examples.

One should bre aware that inversion often produces a text with an old-fashioned, or even an archaic feeling. For example:

> So shall I sleep easier in my grave. (J.R.R. Tolkien, *The Two Towers* "The King of the Golden Hall", Theoden speaking to Gandalf)

This can be a very useful device, and Tolkien in particular makes extensive use of it. But it can be disconcerting when not intended or not in sync with the surrounding text. The phrase "*seldom do I sleep*" used in the xamples in thre question has this effect to a limited degree.